# Xamarin Xaml Front End Design

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

This is the code I got so far and this is how it looks:
[image]

I want to create a carasouelpage where the first one has Three of these bars with ten numbers in each, 9-0, the second one has five and the last one has seven.  But the text doesn't center nor does it fill up the view properly, I want it to take all space from bottom to almost all the way top, with some padding.

But I'm wondering how to create different amount of bars in the different pages. What can I bind to do this?

This is how I create the data template

```
    public class ColorsDataModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public Color Color { get; set; }

        public static IList<ColorsDataModel> All { get; set; }

        static ColorsDataModel()
        {
            All = new ObservableCollection<ColorsDataModel> {
                new ColorsDataModel {
                    Name = "Page 1/3, 3 Columns",
                    Color = Color.White
                },
                new ColorsDataModel {
                    Name = "Page 2/3, 5 Columns",
                    Color = Color.Green
                },
                new ColorsDataModel {
                    Name = "Page 3/3, 7 Columns",
                    Color = Color.Blue
                }
            };
        }
    }
}

public partial class MainPage : CarouselPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ItemsSource = ColorsDataModel.All;
        }
    }
}


<CarouselPage.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ContentPage>
            <ContentPage.Padding>
                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness">
                    <On Platform="iOS, Android" Value="0,40,0,0" />
                </OnPlatform>
            </ContentPage.Padding>
            <StackLayout  Orientation="Horizontal"  BackgroundColor="White" >
                <Label Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="Medium" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" BackgroundColor="Black"  >
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Frame OutlineColor="Black" Padding="10" CornerRadius="0" >
                            <Label BackgroundColor="{Binding Color}" FontSize="Large" Text="9" TextColor="Black"  VerticalOptions="Center" />
                          </Frame>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Frame OutlineColor="Black" Padding="10" CornerRadius="0" >
                            <Label BackgroundColor="{Binding Color}" FontSize="Large" Text="9" TextColor="Black"  VerticalOptions="Center" />
                        </Frame>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Frame OutlineColor="Black" Padding="10" CornerRadius="0" >
                            <Label BackgroundColor="{Binding Color}" FontSize="Large" Text="9" TextColor="Black"  VerticalOptions="Center" />
                        </Frame>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Frame OutlineColor="Black" Padding="10" CornerRadius="0" >
                            <Label BackgroundColor="{Binding Color}" FontSize="Large" Text="9" TextColor="Black"  VerticalOptions="Center" />
                        </Frame>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Frame OutlineColor="Black" Padding="10" CornerRadius="0" >
                            <Label BackgroundColor="{Binding Color}" FontSize="Large" Text="9" TextColor="Black"  VerticalOptions="Center" />
                        </Frame>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Frame OutlineColor="Black" Padding="10" CornerRadius="0" >
                            <Label BackgroundColor="{Binding Color}" FontSize="Large" Text="9" TextColor="Black"  VerticalOptions="Center" />
                        </Frame>
                    </StackLayout>
                </StackLayout>
            </StackLayout>
        </ContentPage>
    </DataTemplate>
</CarouselPage.ItemTemplate>
</CarouselPage>
```

Comment: I don't have a good test project set up to play with this, but instead of your `ItemsSource` being an `ObservableCollection<DataModel>`, it is possible to pass a `List<ContentPage>` and create three different files with different layouts for your pages?  The child pages could all take a `ColorDataModel` in their constructor.  If you are taking a large amount of arbitrary data models, then it's worth the time to make something generic, but if you just have three static pages, it may be quicker to make them individually...

Comment: Good Point, will do that instead. Do you have any suggestion how to fix the labels so they actually fill the screen?

Comment: You aren't giving your labels (or their containers) a width.  I'm a little rusty and was better with WPF than Xamarin, but if you are trying to make even column widths, I would use a Grid layout rather than a Stack, set the columns to an even width (Width = "*")  Set your label to fill the parent - you can bind the label's width to the column's width if there isn't an "autofill" type of option.